# windows permission not recognized in php

Tags: php, windows, wamp

I have the following system configuration:

- Windows 7 OS
- WAMP with php 5.5.24 default configuration

I have a file on the website for which I use the php function `fileperms()`, which I need
to return 0777 permission in order to use the file, but it keeps returning 0666, which means no execute permission.

Because I use windows I executed for the folder containing the file the following commands:

1. `takeown /F . /R`
2. `icacls . /grant Everyone:F /T`

Then I used cygwin to change permissions `chmod -R 777 .`
and checked with `ls -l .` and it said that it was changed to 777

**Update:** I know that in windows there is no 777 permission and one way to change permissions for everyone is to use `icacls`, but how can I make in php the function `fileperms()` to return 777 not 666 as it currently does under windows. If I use linux the function returns 777 as it should, after of course executing `chmod -R 777`.

Comment: There is no `777` permission under Windows. Maybe `Full Control` to `Everyone` ..

Comment: cygwin can only emulate features that are not directly supported by Windows, like Unix file permissions.

Comment: 666 is probably closest to correct (or 660 even). 777 means you can EXECUTE it, which doesn't really have an equivalent in Windows except the file extension... You may end up having to do your own file extension testing for .exe, .bat, etc.

Also, I believe if you wanted to use cygwin to manage your file system that way, you may also need to compile PHP via cygwin and run it that way so it will use the cygwin libraries instead of the Windows ones. I have never tried this so I don't know how successful it would be...